# Multiple subdomains + entry points in React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am building a web app using React, TypeScript, Ant Design and mobX. I used this as a [boilerplate](https://github.com/evolify/react-mobx-ts-antd).

I am creating something that I would like to build on two subdomains, one for customers (www.my-app-name.com) and one for admins (admin.my-app-name.com).

I don't want to create a whole other project for the admin side, as there is a lot of code that would have to be copied and I don't want to do that. I have multiple questions:

1. Is the way to go, creating multiple entry points using Webpack? If yes, how? and then how would I change the scripts in package.json to `start` and `build` those two "sites"
2. I am hosting the app on Google App Engine, is it possible to host multiple subdomains using the different build folders that would be created from my previous question?

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = () => {
    const prod = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
    const styleLoader = (loaders = []) => [
        prod ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        ...loaders
    ];

    return {
        mode: prod ? 'production' : 'development',
        devtool: prod ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
        entry: './src/index.tsx',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve('./build'),
            filename: prod ? 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js' : 'js/[name].js',
            publicPath: ''
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(jsx?|tsx?)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: 'babel-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: styleLoader()
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: styleLoader([
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                implementation: require('sass')
                            }
                        }
                    ])
                },
                {
                    test: /\.svg$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.png$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.jpg$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }, { loader: 'less-loader' }]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ico$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.mjs$/,
                    include: /node_modules/,
                    type: 'javascript/auto'
                }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: ['node_modules', 'src'],
            extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.wasm', '.mjs', '.json']
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: './',
            disableHostCheck: true,
            // host: "0.0.0.0",
            // useLocalIp: true,
            open: 'Google Chrome',
            hot: true,
            publicPath: '/',
            historyApiFallback: true
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './public/index.html'
            }),
            new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
                ...process.env
            }),
            prod &&
                new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css'
                })
        ].filter(Boolean)
    };
};
```

and my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "my-app-name",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot --inline --content-base=dist --history-api-fallback",
        "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
        "git-push": "git add . && git commit && git push"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ant-design/icons": "^4.0.5",
        "@types/node": "^13.11.1",
        "antd": "^4.1.1",
        "antd-password-input-strength": "^1.1.1",
        "aws-amplify": "^3.0.7",
        "ev-ui": "^0.4.2",
        "json2typescript": "^1.2.5",
        "less": "^3.11.1",
        "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "mobx": "^5.10.0",
        "mobx-react": "^6.0.3",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.22.1",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "styled-components": "^4.2.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.3.3",
        "@types/react": "^16.8.19",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.4",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.3",
        "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.16",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.0",
        "css-loader": "2.1.1",
        "file-loader": "3.0.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "postcss-scss": "^2.0.0",
        "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
        "ts-loader": "^6.0.2",
        "typescript": "^3.5.1",
        "url-loader": "1.1.2",
        "webpack": "4.33.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "3.5.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create multiple entry points in a single webpack.config.js

```
  entry: {
    entry1: './src/index1.tsx',
    entry2: './src/index2.tsx',
  },
  output: {
     path: path.resolve('./build'),
     filename: prod ? 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js' : 'js/[name].js',
  },
```

This will create two files in build/js folder, one with the name entry1.js and other entry2.js

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. This does create to js files, but only 1 index.html file with both scripts. Would I then manually copy the index.html file and remove one of the scripts? How would I view them separately using `yarn start`? Is there a way to modify my `package.json` file so that I can do `yarn start entry1`, `yarn start entry2`, `yarn build entry1` and `yarn build entry2`?

Comment: For 2 different entry points, you will need two different html files.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above using two possible approaches

1. Using multiple entry points

```
return {
        mode: prod ? 'production' : 'development',
        devtool: prod ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
        entry: { main: './src/index.tsx', admin: './src/admin.tsx' },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve('./build'),
            filename: prod ? 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js' : 'js/[name].js',
            publicPath: ''
        },
        ...
}
```

2. Second solution is to actually maintain a common webpack config and two seperate webpack config where you merge the common config and override the existing entry and output configs. This way you can actually make two build folder and use separate webpack config while running command scripts configured in package.json

webpack.main.js

```
const Merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CommonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = Merge(CommonConfig, {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.tsx',
    },
    output: {
            path: path.resolve('./build'),
            filename: prod ? 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js' : 'js/[name].js',
            publicPath: ''
    },
});
```

webpack.admin.js

```
const Merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CommonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = Merge(CommonConfig, {
    entry: {
        app: './src/admin.tsx',
    },
    output: {
            path: path.resolve('./admin'),
            filename: prod ? 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js' : 'js/[name].js',
            publicPath: ''
    },
});
```

webpack.common.js

// This will be you current webpack config

Once you do the above, you can use the `webpack.admin.js` to generate admin bundle

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried number 1 (not sure I fully understand 2), but when I do `yarn start`, I get a blank page. I tried opening the inspector, and there are two `<script/>` tags, one with the admin js and the other with the main js... How would I view them separately? Would it be possible to modify my `package.json` to be able to do `yarn build main`, `yarn build admin`, `yarn start main`, `yarn start admin`, and if yes, how?